# Remove node from Firebase with Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to remove a node from Firebase using cronjob and i have this function but when it gets executed I get an error saying "Error: could not handle the request" and the log says: "database is not defined"

This is my function:

```js
exports.cleanStatsOnRequest = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const ref1 = firebase.database.ref;
  const dbref = ref1.child(`/dailystats`);
  console.log('removing dailystats');
  return dbref.remove
    .then(() => {
      res.send('dailystats removed');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.send(error);
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the right way to define the database?

Comment: I believe the right way is firebase.database().ref() and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to access the Realtime Database from an HTTP trigger Cloud Function. [This documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data) shows you how to read from the database. [This example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/generate-thumbnail/functions/index.js) shows writing to the database, which would be similar to deleting.

Comment: thanks, I was looking on the "delete old child nodes" and "delete unused accounts" and i found nothing. now I have a little progress. good job with these tutorials on YouTube :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. database,ref and remove are functions. Read this [guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html).

Also you should not return **dbref.remove()** as remove() will return a **promise**.

```
exports.cleanStatsOnRequest = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const ref1 = firebase.database().ref();     // changes here
const dbref = ref1.child('/dailystats');
console.log('removing dailystats');
return dbref.remove()                      // changes here
    .then(() => {
        res.send('dailystats removed');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.send(error);
    });
});
```